# FTP transfer with resulting files visible to web server?

Tags: linux, ftp, file-permissions, ftpwebrequest

My task is to create a folder on a web server and upload a set of images to the new folder.  The resulting images should then be visible to anyone with access to the web server.  The server is a dedicated Linux AWS instance.

I have the basic folder creation and file transfer working using C# and `FtpWebRequest`.  The FTP server is set to have its local root at `/var/www/job_folder` and folders and files are correctly created within that root folder.  I have created a special user for the purpose of uploading files.

The created folder and files, however, have minimal permissions.  The newly created folder is `drwx-----` while the files within the folder are `-rw------`.  When I attempt to view these images in a web browser I receive `403 Forbidden`.

How can I change my program or alter my folder or user setup such that the folder and files I ftp to the server are immediately visible on the web?  I have unrestricted access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `SETGUID` bit on the containing directory and also set the directory's group to that of the web server - that way any files created in there will inherit the group of the web server rather than the group of the creator.

I mean this:

```
mkdir somedirectory          # create that puppy
chgrp <apache's group>       # set its group to that of apache
chmod g+s somedirectory      # force all files subsequently created there to belong to apache's group
```

Alternatively, you could do a `chmod` in `FTP` after you `PUT` the files:

```
ftp someserver
PUT freddyfrog               # upload that puppy
CHMOD 666 freddyfrog         # let everyone see it (and overwrite it - try 444 if overwriting not wanted)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I cannot send `CHMOD` using `WebFtpRequest`, it is not supported.  I'm using `lighttpd`, not `apache`.   It seems to run under a user www-data and that user belongs to no groups *other than* www-data.  I have added my ftp user to that group, and done `chgrp` on the directory -- now my ftp user cannot create subdirectories.

Comment: Can you try modifying your FTP user's `umask` in his login profile using `umask 022`?

Comment: No-one else seems to be having much luck either... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660121/how-to-change-directory-permissions-chmod-on-ftp-server-using-ftpwebrequest-webr

Comment: If you have unrestricted access to the server, you should really set up `ssh` then you can use `scp`...

Comment: When I type `umask` when logged in as the ftp user, I see `0022`.  Does that mean I'm already there?

Comment: I have ssh set up.  I was *hoping* to do this with stock dot Net which does not seem to have scp baked in.

Comment: I think I may have it -- only trouble is the root directory (the one into which my ftp user creates folders) seems to require 0777 permission.  0755 gives me a permissions error when I try to create directories.